# Do further prime numbers of the form $n^n+\varphi(n)$ exist?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function

> Can the expression $$n^n+\varphi(n)$$ be a prime number for some integer $n>19$ ?

For $n=1,2,3,19$ and no other positive integer $n\le 3\ 000$, the expression is prime. A further prime of the desired form must have more than $10\ 000$ digits. For $n>2$, only odd $n$ need to be considered because $\varphi(n)$ is even for $n>2$

Moreover, I search a prime factor of the composite $283$-digit number $$f(133)=133^{133}+108$$ Probably , there is no prime factor with $20$ digits or less.

Comment: You only need to check values of $n$ that are square-free, since if $p^2\mid n$ then $p\mid \phi(n)$ and hence $p\mid n^n+\phi(n).$

Comment: Does not exist for $n\le 2000$. Checking more currently. Edit: didn't see you already checked. I'll let it run some more and let you know.

Comment: @ElliotG Thank you for the doublecheck!

Comment: @ElliotG A doublecheck is always welcome! Which program do you use ? Python ? PARI ? Unfortunately, neither factordb nor pfgw seem to support the totient-function.

Comment: Any reason for why this expression in particular?

Comment: @Wojowu No, I just like to play around with expressions.

Comment: I'm using Mathematica. Here's a single line to check between 3 and 5k. I've excluded even numbers and non-squarefree numbers. Table[PrimeQ[n^n + EulerPhi[n]], {n, Select[Table[n, {n, 3000, 5000}], OddQ[#] && SquareFreeQ[#] &]}]

Comment: No primes for $n\le 5000$.

Comment: I also checked with PARI/GP : No further prime for $n\le 5\ 000$

Comment: $f(7069)$ is probable-prime! http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000000213091855&open=prime&basetocheck=101

Comment: Apparently, upto $n=10^4$, we only have $5$ primes : $n=1,2,3,19,7069$

Comment: Surprisingly, no composite $n$ so far gives a prime. Is there a reason for this, or is it just a coincidence ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you found no prime with composite $n$ for $n \leq 10^4$ the only explanation that I am aware of is that $\phi(n)$ is very likely to have form $\phi(n)=2r(n)$, where $r(n)$ is either a prime dividing $n$ or is divisible by a prime that also divides $n$.

So, further study of function $\phi$ is needed, that is, to determine for which $n$ we have that there is a prime $p$ that divides both $n$ and $\phi(n)$.

It could be that quite often we have $\phi (n)=m(n) \cdot p(n)$, where $m(n)$ is even and $p(n)$ is some prime dividing $n$, because then we could not have $\phi(n)=m(n) \cdot p(n) | (n-1)$ because of $p(n)|n$ and that would be in favour of Lehmer´s conjecture.

Comment: This is a nice comment but not an answer.